# wxProgressDialog somehow keeping app alive after death?

Tags: c++, dialog, wxwidgets, exit

I'm having a strange problem with wxWidgets. I have the following code

```
MyFrame::OnDoSomeLongThing(...) {
    progScreen = new wxProgressDialog(text,text,number,this,wxPD_AUTO_HIDE); // wxProgressDialog *progScreen is class member
    doPartOfThing() // calls the update method at the end of it
    ....
    doLastPartOfThing() // again calls update method that pushes value to 100/100
    progScreen->Destroy();
}

MyFrame::update() {
    progScreen->Update(newValue);
}
```

Now here's the thing. I can literally comment out the lines relating to progScreen, just let the process go without using a progress dialog, after all is said and done, my apps exits gracefully when I close the main window.

However, just the use of the progress dialog is somehow extending the life of the application. I've tried Destroy(), I've tried simply 'delete progScreen', and both, every time: I'll close the main frame, the process keeps running, and at some point exits with some astronomical number. The only thing I could think might be relevant, is that the doPartsOfThings methods may call boost::this_thread::sleep, because it involves waiting and whatnot down in my model class. But this *shouldn't* have anything to do with my problem. Or maybe it does... EDIT: I do want to emphasize that progScreen->Update() IS being called from the main (GUI) thread.

So I ask, am I using a wxProgressDialog correctly? If not, how should it be used?

Thanks for your help!

EDIT:

Well... it turns out that removing wxPD_AUTO_HIDE fixed the problem. I'm still not quite sure what the problem is, but the dialog even still behaves as before. App closes as expected.

Comment: How have you setup the parent-child relationship among progress and dialog?

Comment: I passed 'this' to the parent window parameter of the constructor. Made note of this in an edit as well.

Comment: I guess you could try removing the auto-hide style, so you'll see whether the dialog is destroyed at completion or not (I assume otherwise it is closed, and you don't know if it is still there). - Sounds a lot like the problem is not visible in displayed code.

Comment: See edit. Turns out that fixes it. Go figure. You can post that as an answer if you'd like, either that or I'll just post a self answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to override the wxApp method that closes the application so that it closes the wxProgressDialog object before it quits.

> wxApp::OnExit
>
> virtual int OnExit()
>
> Override this member function for any processing which needs to be
>   done as the application is about to exit. OnExit is called after
>   destroying all application windows and controls, but before wxWidgets
>   cleanup. Note that it is not called at all if OnInit failed.
>
> The return value of this function is currently ignored, return the
>   same value as returned by the base class method if you override it.

You will need something like, assuming progScreen is a public attribute of your frame

```
int myApp::OnExit()
{
  (MyFrame*)(GetTopWindow())->progScreen->Destroy()
  return wxApp::OnExit();
}
```

Comment: But it's "called after destroying all application windows and controls"... so why wouldn't I destroy the progScreen inside the OnClose method of MyFrame? I will try this and get back to you.

Comment: I suspect that this is not something one does with a wxDialog. Your quote even says that it is called **after** windows have been destroyed.

Comment: Bad news: When I use the progress dialog, OnExit is not even called precisely because something is still alive. When I don't use the progScreen, and set a breakpoint at OnExit, the line triggered a SEGFAULT, meaning that GetTopWindow() is NULL because it has already been destroyed.